# Unity Crashing on Play, most likely infinite While loop, but cannot locate issue

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

thanks for reading.

I'm currently building a small memory card game in Unity using C#. I have the main portion of code finished but when I press the play button on a certain scene Unity freezes. 
I believe it is due to an infinite While loop, but I can not find the issue. I would really appreciate any help anyone can offer. I will leave my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pairs : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite[] face; //array of card faces
    public Sprite back;
    public GameObject[] deck; //array of deck
    public Text pairsCount;


    private bool deckSetUp = false;
    private int pairsLeft = 13;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!deckSetUp)
        {
            SetUpDeck();
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) //detects left click
        {
            CheckDeck();
        }
    }//Update

    void SetUpDeck()
    {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < 2; ix++) 
        {
            for(int i = 1; i < 14; i++)//sets up card value (2-10 JQKA)
            {
                bool test = false;
                int val = 0;

                while (!test)
                {
                   val = Random.Range(0, deck.Length);
                   test = !(deck[val].GetComponent<Card>().SetUp);
                }//while

                //sets up cards

                deck[val].GetComponent<Card>().Number = i;
                deck[val].GetComponent<Card>().SetUp = true;

            }//nested for

        }//for

        foreach (GameObject crd in deck)
        {
            crd.GetComponent<Card>().setUpArt();
        }

        if (!deckSetUp)
        {
            deckSetUp = true;
        }
    }//SetUpDeck

    public Sprite getBack()
    {
        return back;
    }//getBack

    public Sprite getFace(int i)
    {
        return face[i - 1];
    }//getFace

    void CheckDeck()
    {
        List < int > crd = new List<int>();

        for(int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
        {
            if(deck[i].GetComponent<Card>().State == 1)
            {
                crd.Add(i);
            }

        }

        if(crd.Count == 2)
        {
            CompareCards(crd);
        }
    }//CheckDeck

    void CompareCards(List<int> crd)
    {
        Card.NO_TURN = true; //stops cards turning

        int x = 0;

        if(deck[crd[0]].GetComponent<Card>().Number == 
  deck[crd[1]].GetComponent<Card>().Number)
        {
            x = 2;
            pairsLeft--;
            pairsCount.text = "PAIRS REMAINING: " + pairsLeft;

            if(pairsLeft == 0) // goes to home screen when game has been won
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Home");
            }

        }

        for(int j = 0; j < crd.Count; j++)
        {
            deck[crd[j]].GetComponent<Card>().State = x;
            deck[crd[j]].GetComponent<Card>().PairCheck();

        }

    }//CompareCards
}
```

I believe the issue lies in the while(!test) but i do not know why test never become true.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Card : MonoBehaviour {

    public static bool NO_TURN = false; 

    [SerializeField]
    private int cardState; //state of card
    [SerializeField]
    private int cardNumber; //Card value (1-13)
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _setUp = false;

    private Sprite back; //card back (Green square)
    private Sprite face; //card face (1-10 JQKA)

    private GameObject pairsManager;

    void Begin()
    {
        cardState = 1; //cards face down
        pairsManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PairsManager"); 

    }

    public void setUpArt()
    {
        back = pairsManager.GetComponent<Pairs>().getBack();
        face = pairsManager.GetComponent<Pairs>().getFace(cardNumber);

        turnCard();//turns the card
    }

    public void turnCard() //handles turning of card
    {
        if (cardState == 0)
        {
            cardState = 1;
        }
        else if(cardState == 1)
        {
            cardState = 0;
        }
        if (cardState == 0 && !NO_TURN)
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = back; // shows card back
        }
        else if (cardState == 1 && !NO_TURN)
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = face; // shows card front
        }
    }

    //setters and getters

    public int Number
    {
        get {return cardNumber;}
        set { cardNumber = value;}
    }

    public int State
    {
        get { return cardState; }
        set { cardState = value; }
    }

    public bool SetUp
    {
        get { return _setUp; }
        set { _setUp = value; }
    }


    public void PairCheck() 
    {
        StartCoroutine(pause ());
    }

    IEnumerator pause()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); 
        if (cardState == 0)
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = back;
        }
        else if (cardState == 1)
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = face;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading, I will post a link to the github repository if that helps.
[github repository](https://github.com/PhilipBoyle/PB-Pairs)

Comment: How much objects do you have in `deck`?

Comment: There are 26 objects in the deck array

Comment: Can you double check and make sure there's not less than 26 cause having 1 less would put it in a infinite loop.

Comment: I double checked and there are 26 (named 0 - 25)

Comment: Okay so is it possible that one of the cards has `_setUp` to `true` before entering the loop?

Comment: I checked and I don't believe so

Comment: Try adding that reset for loop from my answer at the beginning of `SetUpDeck`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deck array has at least one card in it that has `_setUp` set to `true` which would make it go in a infinite loop.

The reason it goes in a infinite loop is because it will have set all available `_setUp` to `true` and it would keep looking for `_setUp` that are set to `false` and it will never find any.

The reason you need at least 26 object that have `_setUp` to `false` is because in the nested for loop you loop 13 times and then you do that twice which gives a total of 26 loops. So you need at least 26 objects.

What you can do to make sure that they're all `false` is to set them all to `false` before entering the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
{
    deck[i].GetComponent<Card>().SetUp = false;
}
```

Comment: Would that be "deck[i]._setUp"? Or "deck[i]GetComponent<Card>().SetUp"? _setup is a private bool variable from the Card.cs class

Comment: Okay, so that fixed the crashing problem (Thank you so much) but the Cards are not being set a value their value is infinitely cycling through random numbers between 1-13 from what i can see in the Unity Inspector. This would be related to the deck[val].GetComponent<Card>().Number = i; line I believe.

Comment: @P.Boyle Glad it worked it was a tricky one haha. I'm not to sure I understand what you mean. Is it like `SetUpDeck()` keeps getting called?

Comment: yes thank you so much, I've been stressing out over that for the past 2 days! I not 100% sure how to explain it, when I click on the card image in the scene, it is meant to flip and show the card face (eg. 2 of Clubs) but the cards are not being set a final value so they are not assigned a face (they are flipping but are just blank white) They are constantly being assign new values between 1 and 13, so it is as if one of the For loops nor never exits or something like that. Im not sure.

Comment: I just noticed I am getting constant errors (they keep coming, 999+) while the scene is running saying                     "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Card.setUpArt () (at Assets/Scripts/Card.cs:31)
Pairs.SetUpDeck () (at Assets/Scripts/Pairs.cs:61)
Pairs.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Pairs.cs:23)"

Comment: @P.Boyle What you should do now is try to work on it a little by yourself and try to fix the problems. If you're still stuck after working on it you can ask a new question with one specific problem this way you'll have more people that will be able to help you :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm brand new to this site. Still learning. I will do that, thank you so much for all your help. Hopefully I will get it fixed :)